# Is there a way read the random printed?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to set up a fighting game where it prints a question and you have to answer the question correctly to win the fight. But I a finding that I can't find a way to get the code t read the random question to be read thus meaning I can't get it to read the answer as correct.

I've tried making the random be separated into multiple variables but that didn't work. I haven't had much time to try anything else either.

```
import random

fights=("I run but never walk, I have a bed but never sleep", "What time 
of day is the same fowards as it is backwards?", "3+2")
FIGHTS=random.choice(fights)
print(FIGHTS)
ans1="river"
ans2="noon"
ans3="5"
que1=input("What shall you say?\n")
if ans1=="I run but never walk, I have a bed but never sleep":
    print("You won!")
elif ans2=="What time of day is the same fowards as it is backwards?":
    print("You won!")
elif ans3=="3+2":
    print("You won!")
else:
    print("You lost...")
```

If you answer correctly it displays "You won!" and if you answer wrongly it displays "You lost..." but it can't read what is printed so it always displays "You lost..."

Comment: You are never using `que1`, which contains the answer from the user. And you compare the correct answer with the question, instead of with the answer from the user.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to store the questions and answers in a dictionary and use good variable names.

```
import random

fights = {"I have a bed but never sleep": "river",
          "What time of day is the same fowards as it is backwards?": "noon",
          "3+2": "5"}
question = random.choice(tuple(fights.keys()))
print(question )
answer = input("What shall you say?\n")
if answer == fights[question]:
   print("correct")
else:
   print("wrong")
```

If you are not going to use this dictionary again, you can use `fights.popitem()` instead. **Keep in mind that if using Python >= 3.7 `popitem` will always return the same key-value pair**:

```
fights = {"I have a bed but never sleep": "river",
          "What time of day is the same fowards as it is backwards?": "noon",
          "3+2": "5"}
question, correct_answer = fights.popitem()
print(question)
user_answer = input("What shall you say?\n")
if user_answer == correct_answer:
   print("correct")
else:
   print("wrong")
```

Comment: Even better names would be `questions` instead of `fights`; and `question, correct_answer = random.choice(tuple(questions.items()))`, and then `if answer == correct_answer`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 This is arguable since it depends on the context of OPs code. If the whole "business logic" has questions as "fights", I think it's ok